# JOOQ examples like zvon.org for queries especially join queries

Tags: jooq

Any query with examples like for XPATH http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

a graphical representation to quickly learn or go through

Thanks.

Comment: There's an entire [manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/) with a ton of examples. What are you struggling with, *specifically*?

Comment: Thanks a lot and this is one which i am looking for....

Comment: We can close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/ link has tons of example. We can close this.